# Clojure keyword argument default depending on other keyword argument?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to get an optional keyword parameter that depends on another optional keyword parameter for its value.

Example function:

```
(defn printab [& {:keys [a b] :or {:a 5 :b 200}}]
  (println "a is" a "b is" b))
```

I want the default value of `:b` to be the value of `:a`.  Is there a way to do this within the `defn` macro, or do I just need to create a `let` binding to handle this behavior?

The below function does not work the way I hoped:

```
(defn printab [& {:keys [a b] :or {:a 5 :b a}]
  (println "a is" a "b is" b))
```

Comment: i don't think your example function does what you think it does.

Comment: @amalloy Why did you remove the tags "arguments" "parameter-passing" "optional-parameters", and "keyword-argument"? I don't understand.

Comment: Tags are for helping people with relevant knowledge find your question. Just loading up with a bunch of tags doesn't help, if nobody is following those tags: you don't need an "arguments" expect (does such a thing exist?), you need a "clojure" expert. Most language-related questions don't really need any secondary tags; they're mostly useful if the problem centers around some third-party library or something.

Comment: @amalloy Could you point out an example of a question that appropriately uses one of these tags? Do you mean that general questions about a language should not use secondary tags?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to find that there are *no* appropriate uses of any of those tags. Certainly there's no useful common thread if you look through, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments. If you have a general question about a language, there's not much value in adding a word salad of secondary tags. Only use a tag if you think it's plausible someone would be following that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this without using a let. Part of the problem is the colon prefixes in the map of defaults, which should be omitted.  I think you'll also need a reference to the whole map of arguments for it to work.  The following appears to do it:

```
(defn printab [& {:keys [a b] :as m :or {a 5 b (:a m 5)}}]
  (println "a is" a "b is" b))
```

Comment: you can shorten the `:or {a 5 b (or (:a m) 5)}` part to just `:or {a 5 b (:a m 5)}`